# Can somebody explain the relation of Young diagrams and particle physics?

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, group-representations, quarks, mesons

I have the mesons octet and there are Young diagrams below them. how are they drawn? what do they represent?

Comment: you should give a link . this seems relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1155091/

Comment: Please try to give sufficient context so that answerers can know what exactly you're after. For instance, describe in more detail where you "have" a mesons octet and a Young diagram, give a link to the source, explain what you know. Do you already know what a Young diagram is and just want to know why it appears in physics, or do you have no idea what you're looking at? Help us to help you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a deep connection between representation of the permutation groups and representations of the unitary groups.

As a result, Young diagrams (the tableaux are diagrams with boxes filled with some index) can be used to label not only representations of $S_n$ but also $n$-particle representations of U(m), provided the diagrams with $n$ boxes have at most $m$ rows.

For an $n$-particle system, a diagram will contain a total of $n$ boxes, so that the number of boxes in row $k$ is less or equal to the number of boxes in row $k-1$.

Without getting too technical, the diagrams also encapsulate some basic features of the permutation symmetry of the states;  the diagrams can be used to construct Young symmetrizers, from which one can obtain *one* state in the irrep and then, using ladder operators in the $su(m)$ algebra, obtain the remaining states.   When the dimension of the irrep is large, this can be quite an effort.

In particular, a Young diagram with a single row must correspond to a fully symmetric (under permutation of particle labels) representation, whereas a Young with a single column of $m$ boxes corresponds to a fully antisymmetric state.  The other diagrams describes representations where states have mixed symmetries under permutation of particles indices.

Note that hep theorists tend to use Young diagrams whereas much of the standard math literature labels irreps using Dynkin labels.  From the Young diagram $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots p_m\}$ with $\sum_k p_k=n$ and $p_k\ge p_{k+1}$ it is also easy to obtain the $m-1$ Dynkin labels of the irrep: 
$\lambda_k=p_k-p_{k+1}$.

Finally, for algebras other than $su(m)$, say the orthogonals or the symplectics, the Young diagrams are not used so much because the connection between the diagrams and the representations is much much more complicated.

There are many sources on the web for this (see for instance [this one](http://physics.indiana.edu/~sg/p622/LittleAboutGroupTheory.pdf).)  An excellent book on this is the older text (recently reprinted) by D. Lichtenberg, *Unitary symmetry and elementary particles*, Elsevier, 2012